# Statistics & other add-on tools for Planet blog aggregator software

Tags: python, add-on

The Planet software is often used for particular topics or large projects, to collect blogs that post on a particular theme. http://www.planetplanet.org/

I think there are lots of interesting add-ons that could be done for it but so far I haven't seen any. Does anyone know any? (Because of the name, it's kinda hard to search for...)

Like:
- for users, subscribe to a planet, but block particular posters (maybe some kind of Greasemonkey script for google reader?)
- Statistics for a planet - how long have various blogs been 'members', how regularly do each of them post? Which posters typically get the most comments?

BTW this should have the tag "planet" :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: No, there are no addons afaik. You could write them. :-)